# Question about bijective function when restricting domain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f(x):x^3-x$.  By an appropriate restriction of the domain and range to find a bijective function $g$.  Then graph $g$ and $g^{-1}$.

The function I found is $g=f|_{\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]}$.  So $g:\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right] \to \left[-\frac{3}{8}, \frac{3}{8}\right]$.  This function is both one to one and onto.

My problem is trying to explicitly find $g^{-1}$ so I can graph it.

Comment: is that g = f on (-1/2, 1/2) ?

Comment: @Rustyn: The domain given in the restriction doesn’t match the one in the description. It should probably be closed in both places, but emka will have to tell us which was intended.

Comment: @Brian Yes, that was an oversight on my part.  $f$ restricted to $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ is $g$.

Comment: As long as you need only a reasonable sketch of the graph, the easiest way to graph $g^{-1}$ is to use the fact that the graph of $y=g^{-1}(x)$ is the reflection of the graph of $y=g(x)$ in the line $y=x$.

Comment: So $g^{-1}(x)=-x^3+x$?

Comment: @emka $g^{-1}(x)$ is actually a lot more complicated.

Comment: No, the reflection of $y=x^3-x$ in the line $y=x$ is not $y=-x^3+x$; that’s the reflection in the $x$-axis, the line $y=0$.

Comment: $-x^3+x$ is a formula for $-g$ rather than $g^{-1}$. There need not always be a formula for an inverse of a function.  If that exponent 3 was a 5, there is no formula that would work. You should be able to to graph functions without graphing lots of points.

Comment: @Brian: I would not graph $g$ and $g^{-1}$ on the same set of axes because their domains differ. Have you graphed $g(x)=tan(x)$ for $x \in (\ -\pi/2  \ ,\ \pi/2 \ )$ and $arctan(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ on the same set of axes?

Comment: @Barbara: Of course you can graph $g$ and $g^{-1}$ on the same set of axes: both are partial functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. And yes, I have done so.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott We differ on this then. I have no problem looking at the graph of a function next to the graph of its inverse but looking at them on the same axes if the domains differ I find confusing and I do not believe I have seen it doneon the same axes for \tan and \arctan in any of the calculus text books I have used.

Comment: @Barbara: Then those textbooks are missing an opportunity to clarify the relationship between a function and its inverse. I have certainly seen it done, and I have done it myself many times at the blackboard. I gave away a mountain of calculus texts when I retired, so I can’t do a very thorough search, but Stewart’s 1998 *Calculus: Concepts and Contexts* shows how to get $g^{-1}$ by reflecting $g$ in $y=x$, with five pictures showing $g$ and $g^{-1}$ plotted on the same pair of axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ has critical values at $\pm \sqrt(3)/3$ and these are local extrema. The restriction $g$ of $f$ to the interval $[\ -\sqrt(3)/3\ ,\ \sqrt(3)/3\ ]$ has a positive derivative on this interval except for a $0$ at $0$ and the endpoints, so it is monotone increasing with horizontal tangent at those three points and a change in concavity at $0$. The range of $g$ is $[\ -f\left(\sqrt(3)/3\right)\ ,\ \sqrt(3)/3\ ]$  so that interval is the domain of $g^{-1}$. Also, $g^{-1}$ is monotone increasing on this domain, has a vertical tangent at $0$ with a change of concavity there. The endpoints of its range are $\pm 1$. You do not need a formula to sketch the graph of either $g$ or $g^{-1}$ if you have decent graph paper.

Comment: On my first attempt of sketching things I noticed that $g^{-1}$ is just a skinnier $g$

Comment: @emka: $g^{-1}$ has a vertical tangent at $(0,0)$ and $g$ has a horizontal tangent there.  This is the only inflection point. This forces $g$ to go from concave down to concave up at the origin and $g^{-1}$ to go from up to down. The (one-sided) tangents at the end points are also different.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = x^3 - x$ then $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 1$.  This function is 1-1 on three subintervals of the line: $(\infty, 1/\sqrt{3}]$, $[-1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}]$ and $[1/\sqrt{3}, \infty)$
The inverse on any of these intervals can be explicitly found using Cardano's formulae.  You can then restrict the ranges appropriately to get bijections.